# get/add string before a given keyword in kwic

Tags: python, string, list

Hello I'm dealing with keyword in context, I've got the context after my given string I'd like to print also the 3 strings before my given string.

```
def file(data):
    tokens = []
    for line in data:
        tokens.extend(line.strip().split())
    return tokens

lists = []
def keycontext(lines, word): 
    liste = []
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if (lines[i] == word):
            lists.append(" ".join(lines[i:i+int(2)+1])) #lines[i-int(0):i]+
    return lists

keyword = input("write keyword")
print("You've written ", keyword)
text = file(data['clean_text'])
result = keycontext(text,keyword)
```

As output of lists I got this

> ['faire un nouveau',  'faire et qui',  'faire avec les',  'faire au
>   vrai', ....

I want also get string before **faire**

How can I deal with this line

```
lists.append(" ".join(lines[i:i+int(2)+1])) #lines[i-int(0):i]+
```

Comment: What do you mean `I want also get string before faire`? Can you please post expected output also with input

Comment: For example my text file has sentences like. 
_Il eût trouvé plus court de **faire** un nouveau roman_. my function output only [**faire** un nouveau].
I want that it output: [court de **faire** un nouveau roman].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I come up to it by just changing the sliding `int` from 0 to 2. Here is how it looks like the lists.

```
lists.append(" ".join(lines[i-int(2):i]+lines[i:i+int(2)+1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

- from your comment what i understood is that you need 2 words before word match. You can add condition for that.

```
def file(data):
    tokens = []
    for line in data:
        tokens.extend(line.strip().split())
    return tokens

lists = []
def keycontext(lines, word): 
    liste = []
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if (lines[i] == word):
            lists.append(" ".join(lines[min(0,i-2):i+int(2)+1])) #lines[i-int(0):i]+
    return lists

keyword = input("write keyword")
print("You've written ", keyword)
text = file(data['clean_text'])
result = keycontext(text,keyword)
```